# Why is Debug.Trace evil?

Tags: haskell

I've seen many resources strongly encouraging programmers to not use `Debug.Trace` from production code because of the lack of referential transparency.  I still don't fully understand the problem though, and can't seem to locate the underlying reason.

My understanding is that tracing *cannot* alter the output of any expression (though it can in some cases cause expressions to be executed in a different order, or cause an expression to be evaluated that would have otherwise been lazily skipped).  So tracing *cannot* affect the output of a pure function.  It can't throw any sort of errors.  So why is it fought against so strongly?  (If any of my assumptions above are incorrect, please point it out!).  Is it just a philosophical debate, or a performance thing, or could it actually introduce a bug in some way?

When programming in other, less strict languages, I often find it valuable to have a production application log values of interest to help diagnose issues that I am unable to reproduce locally.

Comment: Well not using `Debug.Trace` from **production** code isn't far fetched. You shouldn't use **debug** features in **production** code in *any* programming language, unless you absolutely and unequivocally know what you are doing (thats said without knowing the specifics of what you are asking about, I'm not great with haskell - just common sense).

Comment: @Polygnome that should be an answer.

Comment: @Polygnome: Indeed.  Perhaps I should have really asked why it's bad to use `unsafePerformIO` to log a message from a production build (which is what `Debug.Trace` does)

Comment: @HTNW No it shouldn't be. It might be common sense, but it doesn't answer the question *why* it is bad at all.

Comment: It's like debugging with `print` statements in a lot of languages. It is usually a poor man's solution: better tools exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I often find it valuable to have a production application log values of interest to help diagnose issues that I am unable to reproduce locally.

This can be okayish. For example, GHC can be run with options that turn on various tracing features. The resulting logs may be useful for investigating bugs. That said, the wild nature of the output from "pure" code can make it a bit hard to put the various events in a sensible order. For example, `-ddump-inlinings` and `-ddump-rule-rewrites` output may be interleaved with other output. So developers have the convenience of working with more "pure" code, but at the expense of logs that are trickier to pick through. It's a trade-off.

Comment: Thank you.  This answer probably isn't the best answer to the _stated_ question (which was about `trace` when I really should have been asking about `unsafePerformIO`), but it gave me the information I was seeking.

Answer (score 11):

Of course `trace foo bar` can throw more errors than `bar`: it can (will) throw any errors `foo` throws!

But that's not really the reason to avoid it. The real reason is that you typically want the programmer to have control over the order that output happens. You don't want your debug statement saying "Foo is happening!" to interrupt itself and say "Foo is hapBar is happening!pening!", for example; and you don't want a latent debugging statement to languish unprinted just because the value it wraps never ended up being needed. The right way to control that order is to admit you are doing `IO` and reflect that in your type.

Comment: Yes of course.  I was merely thinking about the case where `foo` was an expression that was already evaluated for other reasons, but I didn't think through the fact that `foo` could of course throw an error if the expression is only used for the call to `trace` or would otherwise not be evaluated.

Comment: but isn't that just a limitation of `trace` in general though?  Given what you just said, why even use it in development? But some people _do_ use it because they find it helpful.  Why is the usefulness of `trace` limited to development and not valid in production?

Comment: @NathanWilson Often during development we are willing to make small sacrifices (e.g. give up control over printing order) in the name of expedience. It is occasionally useful during development to speed up our understanding of where the code has gone wrong; and in small doses, the problems listed above are less painful. But a large system with `trace`s scattered throughout would be unmanageable.

Comment: If you'll permit me a follow-up question, (I'm realizing my question shouldn't really be about `trace` at all, but rather "why is unsafe IO _for the purposes of logging_ considered evil?"):  If you could imagine a function that logged some expression's value in a more robust way than `trace`, where it didn't affect the performance of the thread you're in, and it processed all messages in order (like with an Actor), but used unsafe IO, would you consider it evil?  It wouldn't affect any program output, so why bother with `IO`?

Comment: @NathanWilson I can't imagine a function that processed all messages in order, and I suspect that if you can you haven't yet understood lazy evaluation. I encourage you to read through [Tackling the Awkward Squad](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/552-2008/resources/awkward.pdf) by SPJ; it discusses in some detail why laziness and IO are incompatible.

Comment: I'm sorry, by "process messages in order" I don't mean that the messages should be logged in a predefined order, but rather just that the logger won't trip over itself as per the example you gave in your answer.  So if function `f` logged something and function `g` logged something else, it doesn't matter whether `f`'s message or `g`'s message gets logged first, just that one message will be completely logged before starting the next one.  (The logger itself would obviously need IO to do this, but there's no technical reason why a "pure" caller couldn't use unsafe IO with the desired effect)

Comment: @NathanWilson What kind of logging are you talking about? The way I use production logs is to write messages before or after certain actions so I can know something about how the execution went. In that case, `unsafePerformIO`'s lack of order would be pretty bad -- messages would be shuffled or (after a crash) missing. I can see some value in instrumentation though, when you don't want to determined what happened when during potential failure, but instead just want a count of certain events in a working program.

Comment: @thatotherguy, I'm talking about log messages where you want to inspect the value of some intermediate step of a transformation.  If I have a really complex transformation, and it's not working correctly for some given input, it helps if I can see what some of the intermediate transformations output.  Of course, order doesn't matter in that case.  I would hate to make an otherwise pure transformation use IO just so that I can inspect different stages of it.

Comment: @NathanWilson, `trace` is just rather fragile and hard to control, and it also does not cause the types to tell you what's going on (which is something we love about Haskell). Something to consider is putting the transformation in a `Writer` monad (instead of going all the way to `IO`).  Then you would have a way to access and transform the intermediate steps programmatically, rather than just printing them to a screen/log.  If you think you'd want that.  Sounds like you're mainly debugging though, I'd say go nuts.  But once you get your algorithm correct, it's worth formalizing.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Thanks for posting that article!  I really appreciate the quote about `unsafePerformIO`: "Whenever you use it, you are promising the compiler that the timing of this I/O operation, relative to all the other I/O operations of the program, does not matter. You must undertake this proof obligation, because the compiler cannot do it for you; that is what the 'unsafe' prefix means,"  which points out that `trace` is bad specifically in those scenarios for which the timing/order of logs would matter.

Comment: @NathanWilson, you can write an mtl-style `MonadLogger` class that only offers a `Monad` superclass and a `logMessage` method. Actions with that constraint are "pure except for logging". You can even offer an instance for `Identity` that throws the log messages away.

Answer (score 4):

`Debug.Trace.trace` breaks referential transparency.

An expression such as `let x = e in x+x`, by referential tranparency, must be equivalent to `e+e`, no matter what `e` is.

However,

```
let x = trace "x computed!" 12
in x+x
```

will (likely) print the debug message *once*, while

```
trace "x computed!" 12 + trace "x computed!" 12
```

will (likely) print the debug message *twice*. This should not happen.

The only pragmatic way out of this is to regard the output as a "side effect we should not depend on". We already do this in pure code: we disregard observable "side effects" such as elapsed time, used space, consumed energy. Pragmatically, we should not rely on an expression to consume exactly `1324` bytes during evaluation, and write code which breaks after the new compiler is able to optimize that more and save `2` more bytes. Similarly, production code should never rely on the presence of `trace` messages.

(Above, I write "likely" since this is what I think GHC does at the moment, but in principle another compiler could optimize`let x=e in ...` by inlining `e` which would cause multiple `trace` messages.)

Comment: "Similarly, production code should never rely on the presence of trace messages."  Agreed.  I understand that the compiler could cause a trace message to show up an indeterminate amount of times (including 0!), but is that really enough reason to not use it in production?  I would consider log messages useful even if their occurrence was indeterminate (and in fact that might even give you insight into whether a value was used or not).  When I'm debugging, the more information I have, the easier I can reach a good conclusion.

Comment: @NathanWilson From my point of view, you can leave `trace` in production and log that, if you wish. However, when you read the log, you have to cope with the fact that it is unreliable. That might mislead the programmer in believing something wrong. As long as the programmer is very weary, it should be OK-ish. If possible, I'd rather keep a reliable log, which I can completely trust during debugging.